negative voltage on PCB
I am really confused about how I am supposed to implement negative voltages on PCB, especially on grounding practices.
For example if I were to use a single 9V battery:

Would the negative voltage become the return path? Would that mean I need a -4.5V plane instead of a ground plane?
Would the above answer change if I were to use two voltage sources like two batteries?

Edit: I thought of this question because I am doing a audio preamplifier project so it is for analog circuits (transistors, dual rail op amps.) I think I could just bias the output voltage to have a positive range and it looks like that would be much more simple than using +/- voltage.

Well, are you supposed to implement a negative rail in the first place? Your question hints to it, but I can't tell. What voltages do you need?

It's very confusing trying to answer that. Can you explain an example? You can select any voltage as your 0V reference. And you can use one or two 9V batteries as the supply in any way you want regardless of which point you define to be 0V. The batteries do not care what is 0V, the battery simply has 9V differential voltage over the terminals, neither terminal is 0V unless you choose so.

All voltages are always potentials relative to a common 0V. In a system with a battery, that would be the return path going to the cathode. If you decide to call your return path anything else, the laws of physics won't stop you from a strange choice of terminology - but that won't change the actual physics of the system.

Please expand your question to include more details about what you're trying to do (dual-rail opamps?)...

Everything is relative!... "Ground" or "0v" is just an arbitrary point we pick to make our lives easier... If you actually require dual rail power (e.g: -4.5v and +4.5v), then this suggests you also need a well controlled center point (typically 0v)... creating that can be fiddly if you only have two points that are held ~9v apart. If you only require positive supplies, then the battery's negative terminal may be called 0v, and the positive terminal will therefore be approximately +9v. Two 9v batteries could provide -9v, 0v and +9v when wired in series, be careful to balance their discharge.

In audio you don’t require a ground plane as you’re not dealing with high speed digital signals. It is also common to create a ‘virtual earth’ with ,say, two 10k resistors rail to rail and the mid point connected to a unity gain opamp. The output of that opamp is your virtual earth. I’d suggest you look at old audio gear and their schematics to see how they did it both layout wise and circuit wise. It’s a solved problem.

Please draw a block diagram or schematic of what you are trying to do. As Kartman says, if it's audio only, you could very well get around using a ground plane.

I think you're overthinking this a bit. Yes, with a negative voltage rail the current now flows in the opposite direction, that is to say, the conventional current is flowing from GND to the rail, but practically speaking you treat a negative voltage rail exactly how you would treat a positive one. Just make sure all your polarized devices are the right way round!

a follow up question, why is it possible to use polarized capacitors if the voltage goes negative? Ive seen people use them but I do not understand why it works

The positive terminal connects to the most positive rail, the negative to the most negative. If you're connecting from 0V to -5V, positive goes to 0, negative to -5V.
Voltage is not absolute, it's relative from one point to another.

@cr1tical1 Imagine an electrolytic capacitor connected to a 9V battery. If you call the -ve terminal of the battery 0V, then the +ve terminal is +9V and you have +9V across the capacitor. Now instead call the +ve terminal 0V. The -ve terminal is now a -9V supply. You haven't in any way changed the circuit, so still have +9V across the capacitor. It's only your reference point that changed.

Thanks for the answers. How does this work for AC coupling/filter capacitors?

You probably wouldn’t use electrolytic caps in an audio filter circuit. For AC coupling the capacitor is effectively a resistor as it is resisting the change of voltage across itself. If the input goes negative, then the other side of the capacitor will try to follow. If you kept a constant negative DC voltage on the input, then the cap might get upset. You can use an oscilloscope to observe both sides of the capacitor to see what is actually happening.
